# iOS saying the words on the screen out loud for spelling game

Tags: ios, xcode6

Starting to make an application, can't really find anything online but is this possible with iOS....i want to make a simple application that can say the word out loud that i have chosen and then the user can attempt to spell this word.

Comment: google iOS play sound?

Answer (score 1):

[This blog post](http://nshipster.com/avspeechsynthesizer/) by NSHipster describes in significant detail how to use the text-to-speech APIs on iOS.

Here's an excerpt of the provided example code:

> ```
> NSString *string = @"Hello, World!";
> AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [[AVSpeechUtterance alloc] initWithString:string];
> utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"en-US"];
>
> AVSpeechSynthesizer *speechSynthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
> [speechSynthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
> ```